# Python + numpy + opencv stops executing at first matrix multiplication

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, nixos

I have code that performs a bunch of matrix multiplications, and it seems to stop working as soon as it encounters the first matrix multiplication.

Htop show that most of my cpu cores are working at 100%.

I tried running `python -m trace --trace filename.py` but it did not lead to anything. The last 4 lines of the trace are:

```
wgan.py(127):             output = self.layers[i].forward(output)
 --- modulename: wgan, funcname: forward
wgan.py(65):         self.x = x
wgan.py(66):         return x @ self.W + self.b.T
```

and this is where the command freezes, it's not even responsive to `ctrl+c` to kill.

I'm running nixos 20.03, numpy 1.18.1, python 3.7.6, opencv 4.1.2
The matrices which are multiplied are of sizes 512 x 64 and 64 x 784.
Available RAM on machine is 16G, out of which only about 200M is being used at this point.

Any help would be extremely appreciated! Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE 1**
Rebooting the system seemed to have fixed the problem. But after running the code a few times, it got stuck again, somewhere in middle. After killing python and running trace again, the program got stuck at the first matrix multiplication.
Now I am completely baffled.

**UPDATE 2**
Here is a code that fails:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

if __name__ == "__main__":
    i = 0
    while(True):
        mat1 = np.random.standard_normal((1000,1000))
        mat2 = np.random.standard_normal((1000,1000))
        mat = mat1 @ mat2
        i+=1
        print(i, mat[4,4])
```

seems like removing the line `import cv2` makes it work, but I do need the library in my main code. This looks like some issue with interaction between opencv and numpy.

Comment: What is the size of the matrices involved in the matrix multiplication (their shapes) and what amount of RAM is available on your system?

Comment: matrices are size 512 * 64 and 64 * 784, and RAM on machine is 64 gigs. The process seems to consume about 200 mb of RAM, and there is plenty left. I should have added this to the question.

Comment: Hi, could you post a reproducible example that we can test as well?

Comment: I figured something else as I was trying to create an example. I can just run matrix multiplications if I am only running those, and I might have found the culprit. Editing a reproducible example in the question.